# WebAPI CreateResponse with object as generic

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to figure out a way to return an object in my response while still maintaining an understandable return type.

So for starters, I know this works as expected.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> DoMyThing(MyObject myObject)
{
    var result = await _myService.CreateMyThingAsync(myObject);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, result);

}
```

But what I really want is for this pseudo code to work... somehow.

```
public Task<MyObject> DoMyThing(MyObject myObject)
{
    var result = _myService.CreateMyThingAsync(myObject);
    return Request.CreateResponse<Task<MyObject>>(HttpStatusCode.Created, result);
    // or better yet
    return Request.CreateResponse<MyObject>(HttpStatusCode.Created, result);
}
```

Is there any magic in the framework that'll make this happen? Or are there any third party libraries that can do this?

Essentially I need to return the `Task<MyObject>` instead of the `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`

I'm also open to other suggestions on how to return a non 200 response while still returning the `Task<MyObject>`

Comment: Any particular reason why you want the controller to return plain objects?

Comment: @Nkosi I'm creating a contract between `MyService`, `MyProxyService`, `MyController`, that all inherit from `IMyService`

Comment: That's a bad idea. 

Tip.

The Controller is a UI level abstraction. Its responsibility is to ensure incoming request data is valid and to choose which view (or result for an API) should be returned. In well-factored apps it will not directly include data access or business logic, but instead will delegate to services handling these responsibilities.

Comment: @Nkosi, in our cases we're not using it as a UI level abstraction. The services are a contract between various clients, each client has their own UI layer above the Service and Repository below the Service.

Comment: Basically we always expect a valid request to produce a common response. If there's an error, we don't use the baked in `NotFound()` et al, but instead we just throw an exception and let a global handler handle the mapping of an exception to a specific response code (400, 404, etc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with specifying the type as the return type is that you restrict yourself to having to return that type. That may sound strange but actually there will be many cases where you need to be able to support multiple response, such as 404, 200 201 and so on.

To handle the documentation of this you can use the ResponseType attribute, like so:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(BookDto))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBook(int id)
        {
            BookDto book = await db.Books.Include(b => b.Author)
                .Where(b => b.BookId == id)
                .Select(AsBookDto)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            if (book == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(book);
        }
```

Take a look [here](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/create-a-rest-api-with-attribute-routing)

Edit:

In Asp.Net Core you use the ProducesResponseType attribute which can be used multiple times per method

See [here](https://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNetCore/Mvc/ProducesResponseTypeAttribute/index.html?highlight=produces)

Example

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(BookDto), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(object), 201)]
         public async Task<IActionResult> GetBook(int id)
            {
                BookDto book = await db.Books.Include(b => b.Author)
                    .Where(b => b.BookId == id)
                    .Select(AsBookDto)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
                if (book == null)
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }

                return Ok(book);
            }
```

EDIT: Multiple response attributes prior to dot net core

You can use Swagger to help document / describe your API, they have a custom attribute called SwaggerResponse

The .Net port of Swagger is Swashbuckle, take a look [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle)

Comment: is there something like `ProducesResponseType` without Asp.Net Core? I basically need to be able to change the response code.

Comment: Updated with a link to Swashbuckle which is a great way to document your APIs

Comment: Oh that's it! We already use Swagger, so that'll work. I work primarily on our mobile app, so this is my first time dabbling in our API stuff. My experience is with NancyFX too, so that adds to my confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would be the best pattern in WebApi.

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> DoMyThing(MyObject myObject)
    {
        try
        {                           
            var result = await _myService.CreateMyThingAsync(myObject);

            return new JsonStreamHttpActionResult<MyObject>(Request, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Created, result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.Instance.Error(ex);
            return new HttpActionResult(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "An error has occured");
        }
    }
```

with a generic serializer. You can then use the "better" IHttpActionResult instead of a real return value.

```
public class JsonStreamHttpActionResult<T> : IHttpActionResult
{
    private T responseData;
    private HttpRequestMessage request;
    private HttpStatusCode statusCode;

    public JsonStreamHttpActionResult(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Net.HttpStatusCode code, T responseData)
    {
        this.responseData = responseData;
        this.request = request;
        this.statusCode = code;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = request.CreateResponse(statusCode);

        response.Content =
                new PushStreamContent((stream, content, context) =>
                {
                    var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
                    using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream))
                    {
                        serializer.Serialize(writer, responseData);
                        stream.Flush();
                    }
                });

        return Task.FromResult(response);
    }
}
```

Comment: but I still want to maintain the `Task<MyObject>` return type. instead of the `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`.

Comment: Yes it's impossible, unless you use [ResponseType(typeof(BookDto))] and Swashbuckle on top of it to produce documentation. You can't return an HttpResponse and a type at the same time. A controller is supposed to return an HttpResponse ultimately, if you return a regular type, you let the MVC framework create the response for you.